# Pulling Public Account Information Using FB API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to pull information(name, posts, email, etc) of arbitrary public Facebook accounts. I have a Facebook App. However, I am unable to pull anyone's data because there is no "universal access token" that would allow me access every public account's data.

To test the app, I made a dummy Facebook account and gave that account a developer role in the app. Based on Facebook documentation, since my app is in development mode and the dummy account has a role in the app, I should be able to pull its data. Even with an access token where all of the boxes are enabled, I am still unable to access this data.

**Suppose 123456789 is the Facebook id of account I am trying to get info from**

Get request from admin account - `GET/v3.3/123456789?fields=posts`

I expected to get a list of all of the posts from the user; however, I get:

```
{
  "id": "123456789"
}
```

Is it still possible to pull public account data through Facebook? I know that to do so in live mode, I will need to get Facebook to approve a Page Public Content Access feature, but I am unable to get to that point, because I cannot access public posts in development mode.

Comment: Page Public Content Access allows access to public info of _pages_. Users are not pages.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. What option should I select for my app review to gain access to data of public Facebook accounts, if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If this is about User Profiles:

It is not possible to get ANY data of a user without his explicit permission. You don´t even get an ID of the user without him authorizing your App first. For accessing his posts, you would even need an additional permission (`user_posts`). For accessing his email, you would need the `email` permission.

If this is about Pages:

You need to apply for [Page Public Content Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/#reference-PAGES_ACCESS) in order to get access to posts of Pages.

Comment: If a user authorizes my app, how would I be able to pull his/her information? Currently I'm pulling my own account's information through an access token, so does authorization grant me an access token or any information about the person who authorized? I'm using Facebook SDK for python.

Comment: the bigger question is: what exactly would you do with the data? with the answer to that question, it would be easier to help.

Comment: I am trying to pull common information from business profiles and store it in a database to analyze for correlations - correlations such as effect of posts on user engagement, etc

Comment: you are talking about users in your question, but now you mention business profiles...so what is this about? there´s a big difference.

Comment: Prior to applying for the Page Public Access, how can I access a test page's posts of another user? Part of the application process to obtain Page Public Access approval is demonstrating how my app will work to Facebook. 

Once again, I have a test Facebook account with a role in the app, and I just made a test page on that account. How can I access the posts on that page through my own (admin) Facebook account? Getting a page access token from my admin account only allows me to access my pages, not other users' pages.

Comment: test with a page token and a page you manage. upload a video that shows how you want to use page public content access. i have done that a few times and had no problem at all. did not need any test user or test page.